# pip.conf file does not exist

Tags: python, pip

I am looking for the `pip.conf` file to add an URL from which install some packages. When running `python3 -m pip config debug` I get:

```
> env_var: env: global:   /Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf,
> exists: False site:   /Users/myuser/miniconda3/pip.conf, exists: False
> user:   /Users/myuser/.pip/pip.conf, exists: False  
> /Users/user/.config/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
```

So the file does not exist. Why is that? How can I generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit the file manually. You can list/change/delete options via `pip config` command and `pip` will create/update the file for you. In your case it's

```
pip config set global.index-url https://example.com/simple
```

See the docs at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_config/

Comment: thanks, did that way and now the file is created with the right url!